# SubjectAltName with otherName and BITSTRING as hex

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to add a `otherName` to the `subjectAltName` with a `BITSTRING` given in hex format. According to [ASN1_generate_nconf](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/ASN1_generate_nconf.html) the format should be  `FORMAT:HEX,BITSTRING:0123456...`. But this fails with:

> Error Loading command line extensions
> 139796908598592:error:0D0B20C2:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_generate_v3:unknown tag:../crypto/asn1/asn1_gen.c:94:
> 139796908598592:error:220A4093:X509 V3 routines:a2i_GENERAL_NAME:othername error:../crypto/x509v3/v3_alt.c:492:
> 139796908598592:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:../crypto/x509v3/v3_conf.c:47:name=subjectAltName, value=otherName:2.5.4.45;FORMAT:HEX,BITSTRING:1234567890

I'm using OpenSSL 1.1.1f. I assume the comma is the problem. I have already tried:

Everything on the command line:

```bash
openssl req -newkey -x509 -subj "/CN=Test" -nodes -out test.pem -addext "subjectAltName=otherName:2.5.4.45;FORMAT:HEX,BITSTRING:1234567890"
```

Providing a config:

```bash
openssl req -newkey -x509 -subj "/CN=Test" -nodes -out test.pem -extensions SAN -config <(printf "[SAN]\nsubjectAltName=otherName:2.5.4.45;FORMAT:HEX,BITSTRING:1234567890")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed the comma. Quoting the man page for [x509v3_config](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man5/x509v3_config.html)

> Multi-valued extensions have a short form and a long form. The short form is a comma-separated list of names and values: ...
> The long form allows [actually: requires] the values to be placed in a separate section: ...
> If an extension is multi-value and a field value must contain a comma the long form must be used otherwise the comma would be misinterpreted as a field separator. ...

Also `-x509` requires an argument, and even though you use `-subj` to specify the subject name, the config file must still contain a section for `distinguished_name` -- but it can be empty.

Combined:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout keyfile -nodes -x509 -subj "/CN=test" -config <(cat <<END
[req]
distinguished_name=dn
x509_extensions=ext
[dn]
[ext]
subjectAltName=@san
[san]
otherName=2.5.4.45;FORMAT:HEX,BITSTRING:12345678
END
)
```

Incidentally `openssl` knows the name `x500UniqueIdentifier` for 2.5.4.45, and using that might be clearer to users or maintainers.

Comment: Awesome answering speed.